# How Can I solve the logical error in the flowing code?

Tags: c++

No value is being printed inside if condition block.
Where is the logical error?
Thanks.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int fx[]= {-1,-1,-1,0,1,1,1,0};
int fy[]= {-1,0,1,1,1,0,-1,-1};

int ar[20][20];
int n;
int v1, v2;

void fun(int a, int b)
{
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        v1 = a+fx[i];
        v2 = b+fy[i];
        //cout<<v1<<" "<<v2<<endl;
        if(v1>=0 && v1<n)
        {
            if(v2>=0 && v2<n)
            {
               // Not executing 
               cout<<"----------"<<endl;
               cout<<v1<<" "<<v2<<endl;
            }
        }

    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>> n;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
            cin>> ar[i][j];
    }
    fun(0,1);
    return 0;
}
```

SAMPLE INPUT:
 
4
 
1 1 1 1
 
1 1 1 1
 
1 1 1 1
 
1 1 1 1
 
EXPECTED OUTPUT:

---------

0 2
 
1 2
 
1 1
 
1 0
 
0 0

Comment: Unrelated to your problem but please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) And please try to take some classes or read [good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) instead of learning all the bad habits of "competitive" programming.

Comment: @Shuvo mandol Describe what the program is trying to do.

Comment: Tip: use breakpoints and check the local variables for logic errors

Comment: I can't see the relationship between the input `ar[.][.]` and the `fun` function

Comment: @VladfromMoscow actually I want to know why the logical If statement is not working? There is nothing here without logic.

Comment: @Damien Yes there is no logical relation between fun function and ar[.][.] till now but why the if statement is not getting executed logically?

Comment: Your assumption that there are any values that satisfy the conditions is mistaken (you forgot to check `n` when debugging).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/10147399

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have 2 variables `n`, one global (with value `0`), one in `main` feed by input.

`fun` uses the global one.

Avoid (non const) global variables. prefer to pass `n` to `fun`:

```
void fun(int (&arr)[20][20], int n, int x, int y)
{
    const int fx[]= {-1,-1,-1,0,1,1,1,0};
    const int fy[]= {-1,0,1,1,1,0,-1,-1};

    for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        int v1 = x + fx[i];
        int v2 = y + fy[i];
        if(v1>=0 && v1<n && v2>=0 && v2<n)
        {
               std::cout << "----------" << std::endl;
               std::cout << v1 << " " << v2 << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    int arr[20][20];

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
            std::cin >> arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    fun(arr, n, 0, 1);
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/dxFnmF)